# Connection with MSSQL SERVER using doctrine1

Tags: php, doctrine

**I am trying to connect to MSSQL Using Doctrine1**
but no success.
I found Mssql folder inside doctrine/doctrine/connection directory.
So, it seems that we can make connection.

It would highly appreciable if someone can provide solid solution for this.

*note : with doctrine2 I have made connection successfully, but I would like to prefer doctrine1.*

Comment: very useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine 1 does not support MSSQL (support for it was never completed).

Also, consider that doctrine 1 is EOL since 2 years, and you will not get any help on bugs or setups by the doctrine team.

Comment: Seems you are correct, I would lucky and like to use doctrine2, if you may provide knowledge to me, for generating model entities from yml or xml using doctrine2.

Comment: There's loads of tutorials on that on the web. That's another question.

Comment: Yes, I am following tutorial : http://thingswithpixels.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-doctrine-2-part-1 I have made yml and xml files to generate models, but unable to execute $ ./doctrine orm:generate-entities ../lib    My OS is windows. If you know some better tutorial then please suggest.